# iOS App: Braintree and Firebase server functions within the same script in Heroku dyno?

Tags: ios, node.js, heroku, firebase, braintree

The Firebase serves SDK does some basic admin function on the database, the Braintree server processes payment functionality.

Is there any reason to run things in separate dynos? The two functionalities do have nothing to do with each other, but both run on node.js, so I am considering wrapping them in one script on Heroku.